# How to fetch or get device videos from iOS devices like iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've tried with `AVAssetLibrary`, but its deprecated and throws a warning to use `PHPhotoLibrary` for that purpose. I'm unable to find **how to get the local videos from iOS device storage?**

Please Understand I don't want any photos from library, but I need only Videos.

Comment: Do you want to open photo library and only display the movie type content?

Comment: @DipankarDas I don't know anything regarding this PHPhotolibrary, Please tell me how to fetch Videos from IOS Device storage

Comment: Please, take a moment reading the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Asking "write some code for me" questions is generally not acceptable. Show us what you've tried, provide some related code and narrow down your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out the answer to fetch videos from iOS device storage by using `MPMediaPropertyPredicate`. Please use following function:

```
-(NSArray*) QueryVideos{     
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate
            predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeAnyVideo]
            forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];       
    if(predicate == nil)
        return [NSArray array];        
    MPMediaQuery* mediaQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [mediaQuery addFilterPredicate:predicate];        
    allVideos = [mediaQuery items];
    return allVideos;
}
```

and to display them use this code:

```
        CollectionViewCell* cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"videoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];            
        MPMediaItemCollection *cellItem = [videoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];            
        NSString *title = [cellItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        cell.title.text = title;            
        MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [cellItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];            
        UIImage *image = [itemArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
        if(nil == image)
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"missed"];            
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        //cell.artist.text =  [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];            
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
        return cell;
```

Comment: Are you using picker for that?

Comment: @BhavikRathod Nope I'm not using picker